# Alternative for deprecated DefaultHttpClient and get cookie?

Tags: android, apache, httpclient

I used httppost to login. The DefaultHttpClient is deprecated. but how can i get cookie?

I used before in this way:

```
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "utf-8"));
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

and :

```
for (Cookie cookie : client.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                if (cookie.getName().contains(".ASPXAUTH"))
                    return cookie;
            }
```

but now, I do not know how can i get Cookie ?

I added new [apache](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction) lib to build.gradle `compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"`

what is you idea?thx

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use httpurlconnection check below code

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```